# How to restart Cinnamon after screen unlock

Tags: linux-mint, x11, cron, cinnamon, lightdm

I have an issue with Cinnamon that manifests itself after a long idle period, when I use the computer after a few hours of idle, the CPU, memory, etc. all seem to be fine for Cinnamon, but every operation from keystrokes to moving windows is remarkably slower, on a 5th generation i5, 16gb of ram and a 512gb SSD on Linux Mint 19.3. It seems to have been an issue over the years with Cinnamon.

Pressing `alt + f2` and typing `r` to restart cinnamon immediately solves the issue until another long idle period which may or may not trigger this bug.

Rather than having to manually restart Cinnamon every time this issue occurs, I was wanting to set up an automated job that would restart cinnamon every time the user logs in

I have a script setup that runs as a systemd service that monitors dbus for a screen unlock, then runs `cinnamon --replace` but it fails because the dbus monitoring cant take place unless its within an x11 session, the script otherwise works as intended if I press `ctrl + alt + f1` and switch to another tty and run the script. The error message is `Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11`

It looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='org.cinnamon.ScreenSaver'" | \
(
  while true; do
    read X
    if echo $X | grep "boolean true" &> /dev/null; then
      echo "locked"
    elif echo $X | grep "boolean false" &> /dev/null; then
      echo "starting"
      cinnamon --replace
    fi
  done
)
```

Comment: If I may offer a tangential question/idea... it seems you are in search of a solution to a symptom  and not the underlying problem. Has your computer gone to sleep or hibernate during this idle period?  It's not uncommon for some computers to cause issues here, and what you're describing sounds a lot like graphics drivers breaking during sleep, and Cinnamon switching into software-rendering mode, which is much slower.

Comment: Usually it happens when the lid is left open on AC power and the computer doesn't go to sleep for an extended period. If its on battery the sleep usually halts the idle period which prevents the issue. Still I know this isn't solving the underlying issue but its simply easier and will work

Comment: If you want to run some script after the user logs in, try putting it in `~/.xsession` or `~/.xsessionrc`

Comment: I need to do it on any screen unlock not just the Initial login. That's what the dbus bit is supposed to do

Comment: But it would be run within an X session and would have a $DISPLAY. Also, what user is the script running as? If it's root, that user's sessions usually can't access the unprivileged user session $DISPLAY, and/or have that variable unset

Comment: @Egon's comment was spot on. Often masking a symptom is a valid option, but as a last resort. For now, your 1)problem appears to be system-wide 2)has an unknown cause and 3)occurs during/after the system is left for hours in an ACpowered idle state.Theoretically, your issue is equally likely to be a) easily solvable without the need to continuously restart cinammon, or b) a real serious hw issue. Can you provide more info as far as the "idle" state (scrsaver on/off? session lock?) Is the slowdown present immediately after wakeup before unlock/re-login?are cpu/mem/temp 100% fine (way of test?)

Comment: Its not a hardware issue. I  ended up ditching Mint and using Debian which works just fine.